# How to convert one column values to two different column values based on other column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `A` with columns `B` and `C`.

- Column `B` contains digit 2's and 4's.
- Column `C` contains respective numeric values for column `B`

For example:

```
table rows >>> (2,25),(4,6),(2,10),(4,54),(4,20),(2,30)
```

My requirement is, I need the result set with column names 2 and 4 and the respective values as rows.

I'd like the result set of rows to be:

```
>>> (25,6),(10,54),(30,20)
```

Comment: Write the sample table data as one row per row, and in proper columns.

Comment: @PravinV . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without a column that specifies the ordering of the values, you cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a way to order the records in an unique way, so you are sure which row with value `2` to which tow with value `4` to match.

In the example below I have added identity column to initially have a way to distinguish the rows and then use simply `ROW_NUMBER` to define how the rows are going to be combined.

Once, you have such column, the rest is simple `JOIN`:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(   
    [row_id] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[value_one] INT
   ,[value_two] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value_one], [value_two])
VALUES (2,25)
      ,(4,6)
      ,(2,10)
      ,(4,54)
      ,(4,20)
      ,(2,30);

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [row_id]) AS [row_id]
          ,[value_one], [value_two]
    FROM @DataSource
    WHERE [value_one] = 2
) DS1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [row_id]) AS [row_id]
          ,[value_one], [value_two]
    FROM @DataSource
    WHERE [value_one] = 4
) DS2
    ON DS1.[row_id] = DS2.[row_id];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your syntax only working when there are equal no. of rows for both values.  If it is like,
INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value_one], [value_two])
VALUES (2,25)
      ,(4,6)
      ,(2,10)
      ,(4,54)
      ,(4,20)
      ,(2,30),(2,60),(2,40)..................its not working.

Comment: What's not working and what's the output you are looking for? You cam simply change the join to `LEFT` instead of `INNER` to show the additional row.

Answer (score 0):

If there can be **any ordering of the rows**, say if you have an additional column `ID` on which the rows can be ordered then the following may work - Use the `[Lead]` function (read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) to get the next value in the current row (assuming the first row starts with col B as 2, next row with col B as 4 and so on), then we can just get the alternate rows from the dataset.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), B INT, C INT)

INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (2,25)
INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (4,6)
INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (2,10)
INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (4,54)
INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (2,30)
INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (4,20)

;WITH [Data] AS (
SELECT *, C AS [2], LEAD(C) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS [4]
FROM @A
)
SELECT d.[2], d.[4]
FROM Data d
WHERE d.Id %2 != 0
```

Outputs:

```
2  |4
-- |--
25 |6
10 |54
30 |20
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it only works if the insert statements are like above. If the order of insertion is changed, it is not working........INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (2,25)
INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (2,30)
INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (2,10)
INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (4,54)
INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (4,6)
INSERT INTO @A(B, C) VALUES (4,20). .........if it is the insertion order, your suggested syntax not working.

Comment: @PravinV - yes, you are correct. The order of insertion matters in the solution. There has to be some way for the rows to be ordered. You can have an un-ordered rowset at the start, but the idea is, **if** you can get the rows ordered as in the above solution, then it can work.